# Connection to sybase IQ server from .net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sap-ase, sap-iq

I want to connect to Sybase IQ server. I got connected Sybase ASE thru ASE CLient but I am not able to connect to Sybase IQ. I read on net that one need to connect thru SQL Anywhere for IQ servers.

I tried the same but my connection is getting dropped because of the error message

```
the server may not be SQL Anywhere Server.
```

The connection code that I am using for SQLAnywhere(Version 16) is :

```
SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("host=IQServerIPAddress:IQServerPort Number;UID='MyUserNAme';PWD='My Password';");
conn.Open();
```

The connection code that I am using for ASE is :

```
public AseConnection con = new AseConnection();
string conn = "Data Source=IQServerAddress";Port=IQServerPort;UID='MyUserNAme';PWD='My Password';");
con.ConnectionString = conn;
con.Open();
```

Immediate help is required.

Thanks!!

Comment: IQ is not ASE. Don't use the ASE moduls there.

Comment: @frlan :  can u please suggest what should be done inorder to establish IQ connection?

Comment: I'm not a .net coder, but http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754853785.html looks ok for me for a start

Comment: I had already tried everything that is mentioned in the link that you provided.
But still not able to resolve this issue.Kindly provide help ASAP.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?